# readlink: illegal option -- f

Tags: bash, unix, freebsd

Recently the script was working fine, but from some days I'm receiving such message, while running the `readlink -f "$0"` command:

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
```

I was running the following code to debug:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=`pwd`
RLPATH=`which readlink`
RLOUT=`readlink -f -- "${0}"`
DIROUT=`dirname -- ${RLOUT}`

echo "dir: ${DIR}"
echo "path: ${PATH}"
echo "path to readlink: ${RLPATH}"
echo "readlink output: ${RLOUT}"
echo "dirname output: ${DIROUT}"
```

Output:

```
# ./debug.sh
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
usage: dirname string [...]
dir: /home/svr
path: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
path to readlink: /usr/bin/readlink
readlink output:
dirname output:
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: May be readlink binary was overwritten? Check, that stat and readlink has same inode: `ls -li /usr/bin/readlink /usr/bin/stat`

Comment: If you wan to know real directory, where script located, better to use: `dirname $(realpath "$0")`

Comment: @citrin Yes: `1083670 -r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  16760 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/readlink
1083670 -r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  16760 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/stat
`

Comment: @citrin `# dirname $(realpath "$0")
Illegal variable name.`

Comment: `$0` can be undefined in interactive shell. Try `dirname $(realpath "$0")` in /bin/sh script

Comment: Try to check realpath from interactive shell `/usr/bin/readlink -f /etc/rc`

Comment: @citrin `# /usr/bin/readlink -f /etc/rc
readlink: illegal option -- f`, when I try `Try dirname $(realpath "$0")` in the script, it does freeze.

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD do you use?

Comment: @arved `# uname -v
FreeBSD 8.2-`

Comment: 8.2 has the -f option, so your stat binary is modified. I suggest to rebuild and install it: cd /usr/src/usr/bin/stat && make install

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the version of FreeBSD that you're running. Older versions do not support the -f option.

The easiest way to get around this is to use the GNU coreutils port (/usr/ports/sysutils/coreutils) that will give you "greadlink". This is what I use in my scripts.